# The Law Commands Women Keep Silent

Tags: 1-corinthians, law, gender

To which law is Paul speaking (emphasis mine)?

> Women should be silent during the church meetings. It is not proper for them to speak. They should be submissive, just **as the law says**.  1 Cor 14:34 NLT

> Let your women keep silence in the churches: for it is not permitted unto them to speak; but they are commanded to be under obedience, **as also saith the law**. 1 Cor 14:34 KJV

Where in the Mosaic Law does it say women, all women, must not speak, must be under obedience?

If that law to which Paul speaks is not in the Mosaic Law, it would seem that Paul is speaking about the Roman law extant in his time.

So, to what part of the Mosaic Law is Paul speaking?

Note, this is to ask about the Mosaic Law, not about Genesis or some other area apart from the Mosaic Law.